# Which concepts to report in XBRL instance?

Tags: xbrl

I have a taxonomy entry point that refers to three linkbases, one of which is a presentation linkbase. When opening the entry point XSD, my XBRL tool discovers many more concepts than are present in the presentation linkbase, most of which are irrelevant for the report in question.

Is there a programmable way of deciding which concepts are to be reported, for instance by only reporting concepts which are present in a discovered presentation linkbase? Or does a human being always need to read some taxonomy-specific documentation and then select the concepts?

To give the example behind my question. I was referring to the entry point  [www.nltaxonomie.nl/10.0/report/bd/entrypoints/bd-rpt-ob-aangifte-2016.xsd](http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/10.0/report/bd/entrypoints/bd-rpt-ob-aangifte-2016.xsd). (The complete taxonomy is available at [www.sbr-nl.nl/fileadmin/SBR/documenten/NT_2016/SBR_NT_10.0.zip](http://www.sbr-nl.nl/fileadmin/SBR/documenten/NT_2016/SBR_NT_10.0.zip).)

For instance, the XBRL editor of my choice displays concept `BusinessProfitTitle` coming from [www.nltaxonomie.nl/10.0/report/bd/abstracts/bd-abstracts.xsd](http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/10.0/report/bd/abstracts/bd-abstracts.xsd). `BusinessProfitTitle` is not included in the presentation linkbase [www.nltaxonomie.nl/10.0/report/bd/linkroles/bd-aangifte-omzetbelasting-pre.xml](http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/10.0/report/bd/linkroles/bd-aangifte-omzetbelasting-pre.xml), which is referred to by the entry point and which only contains concepts related to value-added tax. The entry point refers to two more definition linkbases, which seem to contain more concepts than are relevant. So I was wondering how to derive the concepts that must be reported for the entry point above, when you don’t speak Dutch and would like to derive the concepts programmatically.

Comment: What kind of report do you perform? In my experience, the concepts to report in instance facts correspond to those referenced by the presentation linkbase. The presentation linkbase is by essence how-to display the data, but you might have to limit to some combination of axis (dimensions) in the presentation linkbase.

Comment: Presumably if more concepts are discovered then these schemas and linkbases refer to more document that aren't the four you started with. Something concrete to go on would be helpful, this question is too vague as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in the XBRL 2.1 specification that directly address your question.

There is something called "*the formula linkbase*" that might produce validation errors from content in the original instance document and the DTS. Within the "*formula linkbase specification set*" there are "*Existence assertions*" and some regulators are using the "*Value assertions*" for the purposes of detecting when a concept has been reported and the value reported is "*valid*".

Answer (score 0):

This does depend somewhat on the filing system in question, but typically, the concepts covered by a presentation tree are the ones relevant to the entry point in question, and you can safely ignore all other concepts.

The schemas defining concepts are often shared by the entry points for multiple report types, so it's not uncommon to find concepts that are not covered by the presentation for a particular entry point.

Comment: Meanwhile I found the following article, which also seems to indicate that you can not rely on the presentation linkbase to determine the concepts to be reported:
http://xbrl.squarespace.com/journal/2010/1/25/having-second-thoughts-about-using-presentation-linkbase-to.html. So my conclusion is that it is good practice to include presentation linkbases that exactly contain the to be reported concepts for an entry point, but there is no formal statement that recommends or even urges taxonomy publishers to do so.

Comment: Yes - as per my previous comment, it depends on the filing system.  That blog post is talking about the EBA's FINREP taxonomy.  That system uses the Table Linkbase to provide definitions of the reporting templates that it uses.  A table linkbase, where available, makes the presentation pretty much redundant and if I recall correctly, the FINREP taxonomy (and the similar COREP and Solvency 2 taxonomies) don't include a presentation at all.

Other taxonomies do use the presentation to indicate "available" concepts: the UK certainly does, and I think the Dutch SBR taxonomies do too.